# How to use eas update?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I am using bare workflow. And trying to use eas update for my react native project recently. After do all the steps on expo docs, I still can’t reach the update on my production app.

Version:
expo-updates: 0.15.6
React-native: 0.70.5
Expo sdk: 47

Here are my steps:
1.

```
eas update:configure
```

2. change buildNumber and versionCode in app.json, info.plist and build.gradle
3. My eas.json file be like:

```
"build": {
    "staging": {
      "channel": "production"
    },
    "production": {
      "env": {
        "EAS_BUILD_DISABLE_MAVEN_CACHE": "1"
      },
      "distribution": "store",
      "channel": "production"
    }
  },
…
```

4. My app.json file be like:

```
{
    "expo": {
…
        "version": "5.1.3",
        "extra": {
            "eas": {
                "projectId": “[my project id]”
            }
…
        },
        "ios": {
            "buildNumber": "2023033008",
            …
        },
        "android": {
            "versionCode": 2023033008,
            …
        },

…
        "assetBundlePatterns": [
           …
        ],
        "plugins": [
            "expo-tracking-transparency",
            "expo-apple-authentication",
            [
                "expo-updates",
                {
                    "username": ""
                }
            ]
        ],
        "runtimeVersion": "1.0.0",
        "updates": {
            "url": "https://u.expo.dev/[my project id]"
        }
    }
}
```

5. My checkForUpdate function be like:

```
export const checkForUpdate = async ({ userRun }) => {
  try {
    const update = await Updates.checkForUpdateAsync();
    const { isAvailable, manifest: newManifest } = update;
    if (isAvailable) {
      await Updates.fetchUpdateAsync();

      const appBuildNumber = isIos ? manifest.ios.buildNumber : manifest.android.versionCode;
      const newAppBuildNumber = isIos ? newManifest.ios.buildNumber : newManifest.android.versionCode;
      const checkAppVersion = appBuildNumber !== newAppBuildNumber;

      if (checkAppVersion) {
          const onPress = Updates.reloadAsync;
          const appVersion = `v${newManifest.version}-${newAppBuildNumber}`;

          handleUpdates({ appVersion, onPress }); // alert
      } else {
        // console.log(“No need to update")
      }
    } 
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('checkForUpdateError:' + e);
    handleAlertNew({ userRun });
  }

  return true;
};
```

6. Fix some bugs and make a commit on develop branch.
7. 

```
eas update —auto
```

Got the message:
…
✔ Exported bundle(s)
✔ Uploaded 2 app bundles
✔ Uploading assets skipped - no new assets found
✔ Channel: develop pointed at branch: develop
✔ Published!
…

8.

```
eas channel:edit production --branch develop
```

Got the message:
✔ Channel production is now set to branch develop.

Users with builds on channel production will now receive the active update on develop.

9. Didn’t get any updates on app(production).

Did I miss something? Please help me.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Is the JS code to force a reload in the app?